# would php code safe from sql inejction without using escape?

Tags: php, sql, sql-injection

```
public function fetchUserData( $username, $noUpdate = false ) {
  if ( DEBUG ) echo "DBInterface::fetchUserData( '$username' )\n";
  $query = "SELECT * FROM logins WHERE username = '$username'";
  $result = mysql_db_query( $this->database, $query, $this->dbc );
  if ( $result && !$noUpdate ) {
        mysql_db_query( $this->database, "UPDATE logins SET last_accessed = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP WHERE username = '$username' ", $this->dbc );
  }
  return $this->userData = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result );
}


public function verifyLogin( $username = null, $password = null ) {
  if ( DEBUG ) echo "DBInterface::verifyLogin( '$username', '$password' )\n";
  $success = ( $username && $password
            && $this->fetchUserData( $username )
            && $this->userData['password'] == $this->md5_base64( $password  )
            && $this->setLoggedIn()
          );
  return $success;
}
```

Obviously, there's no escape function, so one might insert as `' or '1'='1` to make WHERE clause true, and `fetchUserData` will return all rows from the table. But `verfiyLogin` checks user input password with the query result from database which may not be same, hence authentication will fail. Attacker also cannot modify table since `mysql_db_query` executes only single sql statement. Am I right? Any thoughts?

Comment: Even if it isn't possible in this case, why not use proper techniques? Read the big fat red warning: http://php.net/mysql_fetch_assoc

Comment: use mysqli_* function to avoid sql injections

Comment: I was just wondering if it is possible to do sql injection here. This was from open source code, and obviously it is out of update.

Comment: As you have already seen, you can alter the query because the param is not escaped and that is already an injection. Even if it may be unpromlematic looking on it isolated, it could be a problem in combination with other code. So every query that can be altered that way should be handled as security problem.

Comment: @krishna while  `mysqli` or `PDO` should be used instead of the deprecated extension, they won't prevent from writing code that allow injection.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's very possible to do SQL injection with any SQL query that's built from user input.

You should use the escaping functions, or preferentially prepared statements to protect yourself from SQL injection.  However, you can't use prepared statements if you're using the outdated and deprecated mysql_* functions.  You need to switch to mysqli or PDO.

PDO example:

```
$myPDO = new PDO ('Connection options go here');
$stmt = $myPDO -> prepare ("SELECT * FROM table WHERE rowID = :rowID");
if ($stmt -> execute (array ('rowID' = $inputFromUntrustedSource))) {
    while ($row = $stmt -> fetch ()) {
        // do stuff with $row here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can inject your own data into the result set using the [`UNION` operation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/union.html). So an attacker could supply his own `$this->userData['password']` value that would be equal to the `$this->md5_base64($password)` value, for example:

```
' UNION SELECT 'admin', 'X03MO1qnZdYdgyfeuILPmQ==
```

So you should absolutely make sure you [pass the values properly to your query](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/53114).

Answer (score 0):

Data validation is often confused with SQL formatting. This "escaping" you are talking about (whatever you mean under this vague term) belongs not to "injection" but to mere *formatting*. You need to escape strings not because of injections but because of string delimiters and some other reasons.

**Data validation rules may change.** SQL formatting rules are constant. You have to format any data you put in SQL string. Whatever you did to this data prior constructing the query - doesn't matter.